# Button border not working well when hovered

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm practicing HTML and CSS, and want to create a button. I want a colored border appear around the button when hovered. However, I'm somehow stuck and can't get something right. The border doesn't appear quite **around** the button, as well as not showing up completely. I'd appreciate it if somebody could kindly help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and give a solution to fix it.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px #cbd4d9;
  height: 55px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*border: solid green;*/
}
.button:hover .hoverBtn:before, .button:hover .hoverBtn:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: openB 0.4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: open 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) ;
  animation-direction:normal;
  border: solid yellow;
}
.button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:before, .button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: open 0.4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: openB 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  /*border: solid pink;*/
}
.button h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #587785;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.hoverBtn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}
.hoverBtn:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-left: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  right: 100px;
  
}
.hoverBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-right: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.hoverBtn-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  /*border: solid blue;*/
  top: 0px;

}
.hoverBtn-bottom:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

h2.credits {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/*


*/

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
  }
}

@keyframes openB {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="border.css">
    <title>Border</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hover Border Animation</h1>

  <div class="button">
    <h2 class="hoverBtn">Hobbies</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="hoverBtn-bottom"></div>
    <div class="box-img-container"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Mania. You should not need to create a Div in order to make a button and this maybe making your life more difficult. Use `<a>` if your button takes people to another page or `<button>` if some kind of action is produced on the page when clicked (Eg sending a Form). Then, in the CSS for your `<a>` or your `<button>` you can use `border:` to define a border width, style and color.

Comment: @caramba You can drop both. On my laptop the html and css files are separated. That's why there's a link. Also I don't really care about the font much either. All I care about is the border rendering correctly.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob That's correct. I'm doing it to have a general practice, because later on, I'll be having divs of different sections of a website, and I'd like each section to have a border when the user hovers on it. So I decided to go for div right now to make sure it'll work later on too, if it's no longer a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to replace `display: block;` with `display: inline-block;` on both `.hoverBtn:before` and `:after`. This fixes the alignment, then you can remove the middle borders by splitting the styles with the border yellow (`.button:hover .hoverBtn:before, .button:hover .hoverBtn:after`) into two different styles, then remove the border-right on before and remove the border-left on after.

See the CSS changes I made below:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px #cbd4d9;
  height: 55px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*border: solid green;*/
}

.button:hover .hoverBtn:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: openB 0.4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: open 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  border: solid yellow;
  border-right: none;
  width: 200px;
}

.button:hover .hoverBtn:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: openB 0.4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: open 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  border: solid yellow;
  border-left: none;
  width: 200px;
}

.button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:before,
.button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: open 0.4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: openB 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  /*border: solid pink;*/
}

.button h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #587785;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.hoverBtn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}

.hoverBtn:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-left: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  right: 100px;
}

.hoverBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-right: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.hoverBtn-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  /*border: solid blue;*/
  top: 0px;
}

.hoverBtn-bottom:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

.hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

h2.credits {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*


*/

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
  }
}

@keyframes openB {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="border.css">
  <title>Border</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hover Border Animation</h1>

  <div class="button">
    <h2 class="hoverBtn">Hobbies</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="hoverBtn-bottom"></div>
    <div class="box-img-container"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That looks pretty much pro to me but wow, thanks!!!